# How to use multiple inputs with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am working on a site with bootstrap, where the input file does not show the selected file name. So I have a script that does the same.

But here it does not work with two inputs, so how to use the same with two inputs (two files upload).

[image: Multiple inputs with same script]

Basically, I want to use the same script for two inputs. I hope you got what I want.

I don't know how to use IDs or other ways to make both inputs separate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
    var display = e.target.files[0].name;
    $("h5").text(display + ' is the selected file.');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="profile_image" class="custom-file-label">Profile image</label>
<input files="true" class="custom-file-input" id="img1" name="profile_image" type="file">
<h5 style="color: rgb(4, 158, 4);"></h5>

<label for="profile_image" class="custom-file-label">Profile image</label>
<input files="true" class="custom-file-input" id="img1" name="profile_image" type="file">
<h5 style="color: rgb(4, 158, 4);"></h5>
```

Comment: Well, one way would be to use `e.target.nextSibling.innerText` instead of `$("h5")` in the text assignment. By using the `$("h5")` selector, you've targeted ALL `h5` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Select the `h5` after the input, not all `h5` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
    var display = this.files[0].name;
    $(this).next("h5").text(display + ' is the selected file.');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="profile_image" class="custom-file-label">Profile image</label>
<input files="true" class="custom-file-input" id="img1" name="profile_image" type="file">
<h5 style="color: rgb(4, 158, 4);"></h5>

<label for="profile_image" class="custom-file-label">Profile image</label>
<input files="true" class="custom-file-input" id="img1" name="profile_image" type="file">
<h5 style="color: rgb(4, 158, 4);"></h5>
```